# Sequence of integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis

> Suppose that $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$. Show that $\{\int_0^1f(x^n)dx\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $f(0)$.

I'm not really sure to go about proving this. I know $\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n=0$ for $x<1$ so it makes sense that the sequence would converge to $\int_0^1f(0)dx=f(0)$. I have no idea how to formalize this and make it into a proof though. I'm really bad at this so I'd really appreciate a thorough explanation.

Comment: I don’t have the time to properly answer now, but here is the gist: $f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ so it has a maximum and is also continuous at $0$. You can use this and being able to split up $[0,1]$ into $[0,1-\varepsilon]\cup[\varepsilon,1]$ for $\varepsilon>0$ suitably chosen to make the conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f(x)$ is continuous, for any $x\in(0,1)$ the sequence $f(x^n)$ is convergent to $f(0)$ as $n\to +\infty$. 
On the other hand the continuity of $f$ on $[0,1]$ implies its boundedness, hence the dominated convergence theorem trivially applies.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Let $\epsilon>0$ small enough.

$$\int_0^{1-\epsilon}(f(x^n)-f(0))dx=(1-\epsilon)(f(c^n)-f(0))$$
with $0\le c\le 1-\epsilon<1$.
now use sequential charactersation of the continuity at $0$.

As $c^n\to 0$, For large $n$,

$$|\int_0^{1-\epsilon}(f(x^n)-f(0))dx|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$$
On the other hand,
$$|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1(f(x^n)-f(0))dx|\le 2M\epsilon.$$
with $M=\sup_{[0,1]}|f|$.

Comment: This is essentially what I had in mind. +$1$ :)